# How can I sync my www files b/w servers?

Tags: iis-7, synchronization

I want to sync my data b/w all my web servers. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

[Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is an easy way to synchronize files. It is originally for Unix, but it also runs quite well under Windows. It only transfers the parts of files that changed.

For databases it gets much more complicated, you should look up replication if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

The windows verion of rsync is called cwRsync, and works well. However it does not handle permissions on Windows. So all of the files at the receiving end inherit default permissions.

If all systems are on a fast, low-latency network, robocopy will suffice.

If they are in the same Windows active directory domain, using the built-in DFS replication is likely best.

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft Web Deploy is probably one of the most powerful solutions to replicate server content, permissions, registry settings, COM objects, GAC components, and more.
http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy

You can do live sync's (ie two live servers) or generate packages so that they can be applied offline, migrate servers from iis 6 to 7, compare two servers, discover dependencies, sync databases (SQL Server and MySQL), only sync one site, or many,  etc.

It is also included inside Visual Studio 2010 to generate Web application packages that can be easily deployed remotely over HTTPS without the need of being administrator.